# Why does touchesForView: returns only 1 touch?

Tags: ios, uikit, multi-touch

Here my code snippet.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"allTouches = %i, touchesForView = %i", [[event allTouches] count], [[event touchesForView:self] count]);
}
```

And running this with multi-touching, result was,

```
2011-06-26 21:28:28.723 MMMMM[75081:207] allTouches = 2, touchesForView = 1
```

Why does `touchesForView:` returns only 1 touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the **`multipleTouchEnabled`** property of the view set to YES? The default is NO.

Answer (score 2):

Have you `multipleTouchEnabled` of that view set to YES?

Comment: In my opinion, you should check the first correct answer to be fair. Mine was the second correct answer. ThomasW was have a minute faster.

Comment: OK. You're right. I checked ThomasW was faster by *oldest* sorting.